# Live Linux distribution with preinstalled NVIDIA CUDA support

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, distributions, live-usb, livecd

Is there any Linux distribution with preinstalled NVIDIA CUDA support that could be launched from a live CD/USB drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from https://superuser.com/questions/72226/linux-live-cd-for-distributed-computing-projects

> [Dotsch/UX](http://www.dotsch.de/boinc/Dotsch_UX.html) is one.
>
> > Dotsch/UX - A USB/Diskless/Harddisk
> >     BOINC Ubuntu Linux Distribution
> >
> > The purpose is to make a Linux
> >     distribution for BOINC which easily
> >     installs and boot from a USB stick,
> >     hard disk and from diskless clients
> >     and also has some interfaces to setup
> >     the diskless server and the clients
> >     automatically.
> >
> > BOINC Client : The BOINC client comes
> >     pre installed and would be started as
> >     daemon and would be monitored and kept
> >     alive from this daemon. Dotsch/UX 1.0
> >     includes the BOINC client 6.2.15.
> >     Dotsch/UX 1.1 includes the BOINC
> >     client 6.4.5 for CUDA support.

Comment: The `Dotsch/UX` link seems to be dead. Answer needs updating.

Answer (score 0):

PClinux OS seems to be the only live distro having no problems with nvidia drivers. I've got an old laptop without hard drive (broken), PClinux on USB deals with nvidia driver and the Quantum Firefox with no problems at all, which is all I need to connect laptop to the HDTV set.

Answer (score 0):

> Asked 5 years, 10 months ago
>
> Is there any [live] Linux distribution with preinstalled NVIDIA CUDA support

no, not even for a regular [non-live] distribution such as RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, SuSE/SLES, Ubuntu, and so on.

Nvidia drivers, and CUDA which is nvidia proprietary, while free to obtain, would probably never be preinstalled in linux, nor Microsoft Windows for that matter, if not because of licensing and software legal matters but simply wouldn't make any business sense for either a linux distribution or nvidia to include a nvidia/cuda driver version because things move so fast... *do you install nvidia off cd that came with that hardware or go online to get the latest version?*

For linux the generic nvidia driver is `nouveau` and that's what's it's been for the last 10 years, I don't see that ever changing; maybe specifically inquire with RHEL, SuSE, Ubuntu specifically if you want an official answer and technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is one, not free though. LivelyLinux. Has NVidia driver and Cuda on Live Ubuntu 20.04. Also custom installation scripts. You can search for it on Google or YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

MX linux - create live USB with persistence, ALL tools included to install nvidia drivers, printers, applications, etc - then image, or install to hard drive, or remaster the usb stick your using, or create iso.  The system runs on xfce, works excellent on anything I've run it on and I can create a USB 3.1v2 that is about as fast as installing on my internal SSD's.  I do it all from Debian but for people who have a life, MX sets you up, all free however they do ask for donations!